# How to compare two last data each group in same table DB2

Tags: sql, grouping, db2-400

I have the following table1:

```
ID_BOOK|MONTH_BOOK|QUALITY_BOOK|DPD
1110|201911|4|22
1110|201910|3|15
1110|201907|1|2
1117|201911|2|2
1117|201909|3|7
1117|201907|2|7
2114|201911|3|7
2114|201910|3|7
2114|201909|1|0
2114|201908|1|0
3226|201911|5|19
3226|201910|4|10
3226|201908|1|4
4555|201911|2|11
4555|201910|2|10
7888|201911|2|12
7888|201910|2|12
```

I want to achieve results by choosing ID_BOOK, MONTH_BOOK, QUALITY_BOOK AND DPD with the following provisions:

1. MONTH_BOOK = 201911
2. QUALITY_BOOK >= 3 (there was an increase from the previous MONTH_BOOK)
3. DPD> 10 (there was an increase in DPD from the previous MONTH_BOOK). ie:

```
    ID_BOOK|MONTH_BOOK|QUALITY_BOOK|DPD
    1110|201911|4|22
    3226|201911|5|19
    4555|201911|2|11
```

How can I achieve this? I have done as follows but not true.

```
SELECT ID_BOOK,MONTH_BOOK,QUALITY_BOOK,DPD 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE MONTH_BOOK='201911' AND QUALITY_BOOK >= '3' 
UNION 
SELECT ID_BOOK,MONTH_BOOK,QUALITY_BOOK,DPD 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE MONTH_BOOK='201911' AND DPD > '10';
```

Can someone help with the query? Thank you before.

Comment: How come you want 4555 returned, when it has QUALITY_BOOK = 2?

Comment: Do you want the list of records where quality or dpd is higher than the previous month ?

Comment: @jarlh: Because provisions point#3 : DPD> 10 (there was an increase in DPD from the previous MONTH_BOOK). 

so can based on QUALITY_BOOK or DPD. The important thing is an increase from the previous MONTH_BOOK

Comment: @nfgl : Do you want the list of records where quality or dpd is higher than the previous month ? -- Yes

Comment: Do you mean previous month for same id_book?

Comment: @jarlh: yes like that

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID_BOOK, MONTH_BOOK, QUALITY_BOOK, DPD
FROM TABLE1
WHERE MONTH_BOOK = '201911' AND QUALITY_BOOK >= 3 and dpd > 10
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
with table1 (ID_BOOK,MONTH_BOOK,QUALITY_BOOK,DPD) as (
    VALUES
        (1110, '201911', 4, 22)
        ,(1110, '201910', 3, 15)
        ,(1110, '201907', 1, 2)
        ,(1117, '201911', 2, 2)
        ,(1117, '201909', 3, 7)
        ,(1117, '201907', 2, 7)
        ,(2114, '201911', 3, 7)
        ,(2114, '201910', 3, 7)
        ,(2114, '201909', 1, 0)
        ,(2114, '201908', 1, 0)
        ,(3226, '201911', 5, 19)
        ,(3226, '201910', 4, 10)
        ,(3226, '201908', 1, 4)
        ,(4555, '201911', 2, 11)
        ,(4555, '201910', 2, 10)
        ,(7888, '201911', 2, 12)
        ,(7888, '201910', 2, 12)
    )
select
    this.id_book as current_id_book,
    this.month_book as current_month_book ,
    this.quality_book as current_quality_book,
    this.dpd as current_dpd,
    old.id_book as old_id_book,
    old.month_book as old_month_book ,
    old.quality_book as old_quality_book,
    old.dpd as old_dpd
from
    TABLE1 as this
inner join TABLE1 as old on
    old.ID_BOOK = this.ID_BOOK
    and old.MONTH_BOOK =
        to_char(to_date(this.MONTH_BOOK,'YYYYMM') - 1 month, 'YYYYMM')
where
    this.MONTH_BOOK = '201911'
    and (this.QUALITY_BOOK > old.QUALITY_BOOK
        or this.DPD > old.DPD)
```

Comment: for table highestMonth you store in temp table or no? because the real my data big. thank you

Comment: no it's a common table expression, it's like a subquery with a name

Comment: i already try your script above in db2 as400, but no working. Then I modif based on your script with script below:

Comment: `SELECT 
 this.id_book as current_id_book, this.month_book as current_month_book , this.quality_book as current_quality_book, this.dpd as current_dpd, 
 old.id_book as old_id_book, old.month_book as old_month_book , old.quality_book as old_quality_book, old.dpd as old_dpd 
FROM new_default this 
JOIN new_default old 
 ON this.id_book = old.id_book 
  AND old.dpd < this.dpd 
  and this.month_book='201911' 
  and this.dpd > 10 
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM new_default mid WHERE mid.id_book = this.id_book AND mid.month_book = this.month_book AND mid.month_book = old.month_book )`

Comment: But result not same with my expectation. Can you help me, where i'm wrong? thank you.

Comment: in EXISTS what you want is mid.month_book < this.month_book
  and mid.month_book > old.month_book

Comment: but i edited my answer (simplified), you can try it